# Autowiring PasswordEncoder on ConstraintValidator issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, bean-validation

I have created a specific constraint to validate that the specified password matches that of the currently authenticated User.

Its definition is as follows:

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CurrentUserPasswordValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface UserCurrentPassword {
    String message() default "{constraints.current.password}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

The constraint is applied at the field level as follows:

```
 @NotBlank(message="{user.current.pass.notnull}", groups={ UserChangePassword.class })
 @UserCurrentPassword(message="{user.current.pass.not.match}", groups={ UserChangePassword.class })
 @Transient
 private String currentClearPassword;
```

In the validator **I need to inject the PasswordEncoder** used in the application. The definition is this:

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import persistence.models.User;

/**
 * @author sergio
 */
public class CurrentUserPasswordValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UserCurrentPassword, String> {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CurrentUserPasswordValidator.class);
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UserCurrentPassword constraintAnnotation) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String password, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        if(user != null){
            logger.info(user.toString());
            return passwordEncoder.encode(password) == user.getPassword();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

To allow injection I have included this configuration:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor;

/**
 * @author sergio
 */
@Configuration
public class BeanValidationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor mvpp() {
        MethodValidationPostProcessor mvpp = new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
        mvpp.setValidator(validator());
        return mvpp;
    }
}
```

This configuration is included in a higher level:

```
@Configuration
@Import(value = { DataSourceConfig.class, VendorAdapterConfig.class, BeanValidationConfiguration.class })
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = DataTablesRepositoryFactoryBean.class, basePackages = "persistence.repositories")
@ComponentScan(value = "persistence.populator" )
public class PersistenceConfig {
```

The problem is that I get a NullPointerException when running

**passwordEncoder.encode(password)**.

I have looked at all the messages in debug mode and I do not see the problem. I leave them here:

```
2017-01-03 15:04:31 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:448 - Creating instance of bean 'persistence.constraints.CurrentUserPasswordValidator'
2017-01-03 15:04:31 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:72 - Registered injected element on class [persistence.constraints.CurrentUserPasswordValidator]: AutowiredFieldElement for private org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder persistence.constraints.CurrentUserPasswordValidator.passwordEncoder
2017-01-03 15:04:31 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:86 - Processing injected element of bean 'persistence.constraints.CurrentUserPasswordValidator': AutowiredFieldElement for private org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder persistence.constraints.CurrentUserPasswordValidator.passwordEncoder
2017-01-03 15:04:31 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:251 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'passwordEncoder'
2017-01-03 15:04:31 DEBUG AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor:516 - Autowiring by type from bean name 'persistence.constraints.CurrentUserPasswordValidator' to bean named 'passwordEncoder'
2017-01-03 15:04:31 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:484 - Finished creating instance of bean 'persistence.constraints.CurrentUserPasswordValidator'
2017-01-03 15:04:31 INFO  CurrentUserPasswordValidator:28 - User{id=1, username=sergio11, passwordClear=null, confirmPassword=null, password=$2a$10$0eCQpFRdw8i6jJzjj/IuNuKpJYnLaO5Yp9xSJ3itcfPmQNXVhmNyu, email=sss4esob@gmail.com, fullName=Sergio Sánchez Sánchez, lastLoginAccess=null, enabled=true, authorities=[Authority{id=1, type=ROLE_ADMIN, description=Rol de los administradores de la tienda}]}
2017-01-03 15:04:31 DEBUG ServletInvocableHandlerMethod:167 - Error resolving argument [0] [type=persistence.models.User]
HandlerMethod details: 
Controller [web.admin.controllers.SelfUserController]
Method [public java.lang.String web.admin.controllers.SelfUserController.changePassword(persistence.models.User,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus)]

javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:451)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:620)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:583)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForNonDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:543)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:457)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:410)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:207)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:866)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.validateIfApplicable(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:745)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(BCryptPasswordEncoder.java:80)
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Where is the `CurrentUserPasswordValidator` bean created?

Comment: I think it is not necessary, the SpringValidatorFactory takes care of it.

Comment: In other examples I've seen do not create the ConstraintValidator as bean.

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, only a theory. If current `CurrentUserPasswordValidator` is not a bean the AutoWired dependency will never be injected. The reason I believe it may not be a bean is that I expect Spring to throw and exception if it cannot auto wire a bean. I thought potentially password was null, which seems more likely from your stack trace, but looking at you logs it seems fine

Comment: Wait, I take that last statement back. Log out password and confirm that it is not null. Line 80 of BCrypt is `return BCrypt.hashpw(rawPassword.toString(), salt);` if password is null you will get that exception

Comment: Thank you, I'll look at it and tell you. But it seems strange.  I have provide a password from de form.

Comment: Thanks for the help Leon. I had a badly configured @InitBinder and the currentClearPassword was always null. I thought the problem was that it was not injecting the passwordEncoder.